# Where's the best place to file bugs/feature requests for ROS Answers

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, looks like I've found a bug in ROS Answers. What's the best way to report it? The "Give Feedback" link at the bottom of the page? Some Trac project somewhere?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9120/where%27s-the-best-place-to-file-bugs/feature-requests-for-ros-answers/) by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8406 on 2011-02-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have created a component" answers.ros.org" on the ros trac.  To file a ticket follow this link https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/newticket?component=answers.ros.org

---

Originally posted by [Tully](https://answers.ros.org/users/7/tully/) with karma: 1145 on 2011-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Trac looks like a good choice to me. There is already a `doc systems` component, although it seems better to create a separate ROS answers component.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-02-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2